# Multiple file sharing intent crashes when launched from ES File Explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, file-manager, android-sharing

I've written a small file sharing program in android where user can select multiple files for sharing via my app, either from native Android gallery or some file manager (like ES File Explorer). To start with, I'm just displaying the selected file paths in a TextView of MainActivity. Here is my code snippet:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(getIntent().getAction())
            && getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {

        ArrayList<Parcelable> list = getIntent()
                .getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
            Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;
            String sourcepath = getPath(uri);
            filepathNameArray.add(sourcepath); //building file path name array from gallery
                            myTextView.append(sourcepath + "\n"); //displaying selected files' path in textView
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine when user selects multiple files from Gallery, but the app crashes when I select files (for sharing via my app) from ES File Explorer. Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.